# ¿Cómo hacer columnas fijas de una tabla en python con Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tablas

Creé una tabla en una ventana con el modulo Tkinter en python y la tabla es un Treeview, la cual cuenta con 2 columnas (nombre y precio), al hacerla, **me estoy encontrando con un inconveniente**, durante la ejecución de la ventana, se puede mover el largo de las columnas, es decir, **se puede deslizar la línea divisora que separa una columna de otra**, permitiendo editar el largo de las columnas. Esto es lo que estoy buscando desactivar, ya que **el fin de la tabla que uso es el de mostrar únicamente datos**, por lo que **el largo de las columnas deberían estar fijas en una determinada longitud.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la tabla es el siguiente:

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height = 10, columns = 4)
self.tree.grid(row = 4, column = 0 , columnspan = 2)
self.tree.heading("#0", text = "Name", anchor = CENTER)
self.tree.heading("#1", text = "Price", anchor = CENTER)
```

¿Cómo podría conseguir las columnas fijas?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un bind del evento `<B1-Motion>` (el usuario mueve el cursor mientras mantiene apretado el boton izquierdo del mouse) y llamar a una función que haga que Tkinter crea que el usuario dejó de hacer clic con el comando `tree.event_generate("<ButtonRelease-1>")`. `<ButtonRelease-1>` es el evento que sucede cuando el usuario dejó de hacer clic. Con `event.generate` creamos el evento.
Ahora solo nos queda averiguar como saber si el usuario está cambiando el tamaño de las columnas o no. Y se me ocurren dos formas:

## 1- Según donde está el cursor

```
def restrictor(Event):
    # Reviso si una zona especifica alrededor del cursor toca el separador de columnas
    # Esta zona la obtuve con prueba y error.
    for x in range(-10, 10):
        for y in range(1):
            #Si el separador de columnas está dentro de la zona, entonces doy por hecho que el usuario está intentando cambiar de tamaño la columna.
            if(tree.identify_region(Event.x+x, Event.y+y) == "separator"):
                tree.event_generate("<ButtonRelease-1>")
                break

# Hago que mi función sea llamada cada vez que el usuario hace clic y mueve el cursor.
tree.bind("<B1-Motion>", restrictor)
```

El problema con esta solución es que puede tener un fallo que yo no haya notado (debido a lo que averigué con prueba y error), y que si se pueda cambiar la columna de tamaño.

## 2- Según que cursor se muestra

Como habrás notado, cada vez que ponemos el cursor sobre el separador de columnas, el cursor pasa a ser otro. Podemos obtener el nombre del cursor actual y usar eso de base para saber si el usuario intenta o no cambiar el tamaño de la columna.

```
def restrictor(Event):
    # Si el cursor se llama "size_we", entonces doy por hecho que el usuario trata de cambiar el tamaño de las columnas
    if(str(tree["cursor"]) == "size_we"):
        tree.event_generate("<ButtonRelease-1>")

# Hago que mi función sea llamada cada vez que el usuario hace clic y mueve el cursor.
tree.bind("<B1-Motion>", restrictor)
```

Esta solución es más estable que la anterior. Pero tiene dos problemas que quiza no influyan en tu caso pero es bueno señalar:

1-Que pasa si cambias el cursor que se muestra al intentar separar las columnas? Tendrás que poner al día esta función con el nuevo nombre del cursor.

2-Si haces que el cursor cambie de tal manera que sin importar donde esté, la imagen del cursor sea siempre la misma? Eso haría que la segunda solución pierda efecto.

Espero que hayas entendido todo y que esta respuesta te sirva, saludos c: